# Inject a character while concatenating with stringByAppendingString

Tags: objective-c, concatenation, code-injection

Is there a way to concatenate two strings and inject a character. I have :

```
NSString *firstString = @"http://www.stackoverflow.com";
NSString *secondString = @"supercooloptions";
NSString *result = [firstString stringByAppendingString: secondString];
NSLog(@"the final string with "/" injection = %@", result);
```

I'd like the final string with "/" injected = www.stackoverflow.com/supercooloptions

Comment: try this  NSString *result = [firstString stringByAppendingFormat:@"/ %@",secondString];

Comment: In my case Wain answer works best, in general cases with general caractere injection purposes, dasblinkenlight answer works best. Thank you all for answering.

Comment: Warning : stringByAppendingPathComponent method take out one "/" in  the ->http:// <-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a different method - for example, `stringWithFormat`:

```
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", firstString, secondString];
```

Answer (score 5):

For this specific case, use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:`

```
NSString *result = [firstString stringByAppendingPathComponent:secondString];
```